# ckeditor is mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor' really required in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I am trying to load ckeditor based on the info at https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor in a ruby rails app

It appeared that I was supposed to put mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor' in my routes.rb

However, if I do that, I get uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Engine  when I try to load my page.

Does the command have to go in routes.rb?

Comment: Did you restart your rails server after the bundle install?

Comment: Thanks tom - That did it. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I don't see how to mark your reply as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to restart your server after installing new gems.

Cheers!